# For Each Cell... Next Cell Loop Only Works Once

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

My code finds cells in a predefined range "r" that have a value of "Completed", but using the For Each Cell and Next Cell commands does not loop the code to find more than one "Completed" cell.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Move_Burn()

Dim Msg As String, Ans As Variant

  Msg = "Are you sure you want to move the completed pumps?"

  Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)

  Select Case Ans

Case vbYes

Dim r As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long, r2 As Range

Set r = Range("AR15:AR1000")
Set r2 = Range("AF15:AF1000")

mynumber = 1
For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "Completed" Then
    Range("AT15:BN15").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("AT15:BN15").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    End If

    If cell.Value = "Completed" Then
    cell.Select
    cell.Value = "Delete"
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -20)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AT15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("BN15").ClearContents

    End If

    If cell.Value = "Delete" Then
    cell.Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -20)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    End If

    Next cell

Case vbNo
  GoTo Quit:
    End Select
Quit:

  End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't looping? Step through your code using F8 and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I should have said, I assigned this code to a macro. So to test if it moves more than one row I fill in two cells in the range as "Completed" and press the macro but only one gets moved.

Comment: you're deleting cells - that's your issue. Always loop backwards when deleting cells or rows within a loop. Your code is fine, it's your test that isn't sufficient enough to notice the issue. If you filled 50 cells you would notice that every _other_ cell gets deleted.

Comment: Assigning it to a macro doesn't mean you can't step through it.  Set up your test cells then click in the code (in the VBA Editor) and use F8 to step through the code to see where it's going awry

Comment: I used F8 to check and it loops back to the start. How would I loop backwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're deleting cells so you need to loop backwards.

Change your loop to this:

```
For i = 1000 To 15 Step -1
    '// Your code here

    '// Instead of referring to cell - use Range("AR" & i) e.g.

    If Range("AR" & i).Value = "Completed" Then
        '// rest of code
    End If

Next
```

Comment: this way OP won't have it's copied ranges listed "backwards" as it currently has and thus I'm guessing it needs

Comment: What would I replace the "cell.select" part of the code with?

Comment: `Range("AR" & i).Select` Just replace all instances of `cell` with `Range("AR" & i)`

Comment: Thanks! This works great, I thought reselecting `Range("AR" & i)` would not select only the "Completed" rows but it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

with

```
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

you're skipping the subsequent row

do like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move_Burn()

    Dim Msg As String

    Msg = "Are you sure you want to move the completed pumps?"
    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Pumps") '<--| change "Pumps" to your actual worksheet name
        Set r = .Range("AR15", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AR").End(xlUp)) '<--| set the range to be looped as all column "AR" cells fron row 15 down to last not empty one
    End With

    nRows = r.Rows.Count '<--| set the remaining rows counter
    iRow = 1 '<--| set starting row in the range
    Do While iRow <= nRows '<--| loop through range rows by means of a row index

        Set cell = r.Cells(iRow, 1) '<--| set current row index cell

        If cell.Value = "Completed" Then
            With Range("AT15:BN15")
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End With
            cell.Value = "Delete"
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, -20)).Copy
            Range("AT15").PasteSpecial
            Range("BN15").ClearContents
        End If

        If cell.Value = "Delete" Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, -20)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            iRow = iRow - 1 '<-- bring row index back one step since you deleted current row
            nRows = nRows - 1 '<--| update the remaining rows counter
        End If

        iRow = iRow + 1 '<-- updated current row index

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked but came up with an error for the line `Do While iRow <= r.Rows.Count '<--| loop through range rows by means of a row index`

Comment: how could it work and throw an error at the same time? please be more specific

Comment: It runs through the code and moves all the "Completed" ranges but once all have been moved an error message box pops up, highlighting this part of the code

Comment: I see, that's when all cells are marked either "Completed" or Delete", thus _collapsing_ `r` to a range with zero cells. See edited code

Comment: You are welcome. So, do you actually need processed cells to be listed in columns AT:BN in _reverse_ order (as per your posted code, the last processed "X:AR" cells are listed at the top of "AT:BN" columns) or do you need them listed in any order?

Comment: It's fine in any order as it will get filtered by other variables later, so your code works great

Comment: Had it been more clear, I wouldn't have struggled that hard to maintain the _reverse_ order I got from your posted code and simply would suggest to loop through "AR" column in reverse order as @Macroman did

Answer (score -1):

Works in my excel, maybe try setting the r range relative to the sheet you are working in? so:

```
r=sheets("Sheet1").Range("AF15:AF1000")
```

Comment: I tried it but it still only copies over one row, thanks anyway!

Comment: You obviously didn't try deleting rows within a loop then. That's what is causing the issue.